UITextView in UIViewRepresentable: setting isScrollEnabled to false breaks the layout
I have a UITextView, within a UIViewRepresentable, so I can use it in a SwiftUI ScrollView.  Im using intrinsic content sizing to set the frame of the content.  This works great, until I set .isScrollEnabled on the UITextView to false - at that point the intrinsic content size no longer works.  Im trying to avoid the other layout alternative where I have to calculate and set the frame size - this solution with intrinsic is much nicer.  But I cant get around the .isScrollEnabled breaking it.  Heres the code:
struct MainView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            SimpleTextView(text: loremIpsum)
                .frame(minHeight: 10)
                .border(.red)
            SimpleTextView(text: loremIpsum)
                .frame(minHeight: 10)
                .border(.red)
            SimpleTextView(text: loremIpsum)
                .frame(minHeight: 10)
                .border(.red)
        }
    }
}

The UITextView:

struct SimpleTextView: UIViewRepresentable {
    @State
    private var attributedText: NSAttributedString?
    var text: String

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> UITextView {
        let view = ContentTextView()
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .vertical)
        view.setContentHuggingPriority(.required, for: .horizontal)
        view.isSelectable = true
        view.isEditable = false
        view.isScrollEnabled = true
        view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return view
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: UITextView, context: Context) {
        guard let attributedText = attributedText else {
            generateAttributedText()
            return
        }
        uiView.attributedText = attributedText
        uiView.invalidateIntrinsicContentSize()
    }
    
    private func generateAttributedText() {
        guard attributedText == nil else { return }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            self.attributedText = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: [:])
        }
    }
    
    private class ContentTextView: UITextView {
        override var canBecomeFirstResponder: Bool { false }
        
        override var intrinsicContentSize: CGSize {
            frame.height > 0 ? contentSize : super.intrinsicContentSize
        }
    }
}

Output when isScrollEnabled is true:

When isScrollEnabled is false, i just get an empty page.
Thanks for any assistance.

If you add a frame you’ll likely be able to see the TextField.
